# moduli space of curves under prescribed tangency conditons

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We consider an irreducible component of the Hilbert Scheme of curves in $\mathbb P^2$.  Denote it as $\mathcal D.$ We fix a line $L$ and a point $A\in L.$ Denote $\mathcal D_0$ as the subscheme of $\mathcal D$  which consists of curves passing through $A\in \mathbb P^2$.  And denote  $\mathcal{D}_k,\rm{for}\,\, k\geq 1$ as the set $\{d\in\mathcal D_0|\rm{the \,\,curve\,\, corresponding\,\, to \,\,}d\,\,is \,\,\rm{tangent\,\, to\,\, the\,\,line\,\, L\,\, to\,\, order\,\, at\,\,least\,\,k}\}$  My question is if $\mathcal D_k's$ are subschemes of $\mathcal D_0$? And when $D_0\supset D_1\supset D_2\supset \cdots$ will be stable?